# Departments not showing in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin

I have two tables ,departments and users.One department has many users.One user belongs to one department.Im trying to write a foreach loop to display the names of the departments with its users but i get this error.

---

> Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
>   Undefined variable: departments (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\blog2\resources\views\admin\dashboard.blade.php)

create_users_table

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            //$table->text('avatar');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('lastname');
            $table->string('phone');
            $table->string('jobtitle');
            $table->integer('department_id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('usertype')->nullable();
            $table->string('email');
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();

        });
    }
```

create_departments_table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('departments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Department.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Department extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'departments';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

public function department()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Department::class);
}

}
```

User.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{

    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = [];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
     public function department()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Department::class);
    }

}
```

dashboard.blade.php

```
 @extends ('layouts.master')

@section('title')
DASHBOARD | Admin
@endsection

@section('content') 

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="card">
      @if (session('status'))
      <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
        {{ session('status') }}
      </div>
      @endif
      <div class="card-header">
        <h4 class="card-title"> DASHBOARD </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table">
            <thead class=" text-primary">
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
              <th>Department</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @foreach($departments as $department)
              <td> {{$department->name}}</td>
              @endforeach
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  @endsection

  @section('scripts')

  @endsection
```

DashboardController.php

```
class DashboardController extends Controller
{  public function index()
    {
      $users= User::all();
      foreach($users as $user)
      {
        echo $user->department->name;
        echo $user->name;
      }
   }
}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});


Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');


Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','admin']], function  () {

    Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
        $users= User::all();
        $departments = Department::with('users')->get();
        dd($departments);
        return view('admin.dashboard',compact('departments','users')); 
    });
    //Route::get('/dashboard', "Admin\DashboardController@index");
   // Route::get('/dashboard{id}', "Admin\DashboardController@index");
    Route::get('/role-register','Admin\DashboardController@registered');
    Route::get('/role-edit/{id}', 'Admin\DashboardController@registeredit');   
    Route::put('/role-register-update/{id}', 'Admin\DashboardController@registerupdate');
    Route::delete('/role-delete/{id}', 'Admin\DashboardController@registerdelete');
    Route::post('/save-user', 'Admin\DashboardController@store');


    Route::get('/department', 'Admin\DepartmentController@index');
    Route::post('/save-department', 'Admin\DepartmentController@store');
    Route::get('/department-edit/{id}', 'Admin\DepartmentController@edit');
    Route::put('/department-update/{id}', 'Admin\DepartmentController@update');
    Route::delete('/department-delete/{id}', 'Admin\DepartmentController@delete');


});
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

I have tried this too but still the same.

```
<td> {{$department->name}}</td>
```

```
@foreach($departments->name as $department)
<td> {{$department}}</td>
@endforeach
```

Comment: you seem to have modified the code. which is the code in controller that leads to that specific error

Comment: yes i made some changes but this  foreach part gives me this error
              <td> {{$department}}</td>

Comment: Please show the model of the Users and Departments because I think you might not set the relation between them.

Comment: i added now at the queston section

Comment: its hard to tell when the code you have right now will produce different set of results. some things to note. first only gets 1 value so you cannot foreach loop it, if the query failed in any way, then the $departments would be null or false not undefined

Comment: I don't see foreign key relationship defined in your migration file of User.

Comment: ErrorException
Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try this? see if it changes the error?

```php
use App\User;
use App\Department;

Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    $users= User::all();
    $departments = Department::with('users')->get();
    return view('admin.dashboard',compact('departments','users')); 
});
```

comment out this.

```php
// Route::get('/dashboard', 'Admin\DashboardController@index' );
```

Also in you balde file you need to chenge to this, this will give you all the department.

```html
              @foreach($departments as $department)
              <td> {{$department->name}}</td>
              @endforeach
```

**Update**

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Department extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'departments';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207879/discussion-on-answer-by-andy-song-departments-not-showing-in-laravel).

Answer (score 1):

In your web.php,
replace this:

```
Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('admin.dashboard');
});
```

with this:

```
Route::get('/dashboard', 'Admin\DashboardController@index' );
```

In you Dashboard controller, replace this:

```
public function index()
{
    $users= User::all();
    $departments = Department::with('users')->first();
   // return view('admin.dashboard')->with('departments',$departments)->with('users',$users); 
    // $departments = Department::with('users')->where('users.department_id','=','departments.id')->first();
    // dd($departments);
     dd($users); 
    // return view('admin.dashboard',compact('departments','users'));        
}
```

with this:

```
public function index()
{
    $users= User::all();
    $departments = Department::with('users')->get();
    return view('admin.dashboard',compact('departments','users'));        
}
```

Comment: InvalidArgumentException
View [Admin\DashboardController@index] not found. i get this with these changes

Comment: @klearn Firstly, I see you have `get('/dashboard' ... ` defined multiple times in your web.php. Please make sure it's not.

Comment: i commented those parts with get('/dashboard...  in web.php ) but its the same error again

Answer (score 1):

```php
Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('admin.dashboard');
});
```

Here's your problem. You're returning the dashboard view without passing it the list of departments.

This route should be using the `DashboardController@index` ( and your commented code should be uncommented) - which gets the list of departments and returns the view while passing in the list.

Better yet if you used the URL `/departments` and a DepartmentsController...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `User` model to have the following relation:

```
public function department()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Department::class);
}
```

In DashboardController change it to the following:

```
class DashboardController extends Controller
{
   public function index()
   {
     $users= User::all();
     foreach($users as $user)
     {
       echo $user->department->name;
       echo $user->name;
     }
  }
}
```

And update the associated route:

```
Route::get('/dashboard', "Admin\DashboardController@index");
```

Comment: ErrorException
Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Comment: $user->department->first()->name

Comment: dd($user) and see what data is present instead of echo statement